# Como não trazer descrição repetida no parâmetro?

Tags: sql

Tenho um dataset construido para uso como parâmetro. No entanto, vários códigos se referem a mesma descrição, e não consigo fazer com que as descrições não se repitam ao colocar a descrição como parâmetro de busca. Segue a query:

```
with apg_cd_situacao (apg_cd_situacao, apg_cd_situacao_descricao) as (values 
    ('AA','Análise'), 
    ('DN','Análise'),
    ('DR','Análise'), 
    ('DP','Análise'),
    ('AN','Análise'), 
    ('AL','Análise'),
    ('DU','Análise')
)
select apg_cd_situacao, apg_cd_situacao_descricao
from apg_cd_situacao
;
```

Já tentei juntar os códigos (('AA','DN', 'DR',...), 'Análise'), mas não está funcionando

Comment: Tente fazer um GROUP BY apg_cd_situacao_descricao e na lista do select utilize alguma função de agregação apropriada, de acordo com seu SGBD, por ex. array_agg(apg_cd_situacao) ou string_agg(apg_cd_situacao).

Answer (score 0):

Tenta acrescentar o distinct no inicio da consulta.

- with apg_cd_situacao (apg_cd_situacao, apg_cd_situacao_descricao) as
  (values 
     ('AA','Análise'), 
     ('DN','Análise'),
     ('DR','Análise'), 
     ('DP','Análise'),
     ('AN','Análise'), 
     ('AL','Análise'),
     ('DU','Análise') ) select distinct apg_cd_situacao, apg_cd_situacao_descricao from apg_cd_situacao ;

Comment: Já havia tentado sem sucesso